# Regex to obtain two values from string

Tags: regex

I have string like below and i need to pull out two values (numeric values) one is 197kJ (numeric 197) and second is 47kcal (numeric 47). Can someone help me with this because I just go crazy :) ?

My [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uS3mE4/2):

```
((<|>)?\d+((\.|,)\d+)?kj\s?\/\s?)?(<|>)?(\d+((\.|,)\d+)?)kcal
```

String to search in:

> Per 250ml serving (10 servings per pack): Energy 197kJ (2% ADH)/47kcal
>   (2% ADH), Fat 0.3g (of which Saturated Fat 0.1g), Carbohydrate 7.8g
>   (3% ADH) (of which Sugars 3.9g (4% ADH)), Fibres 1.6g, Protein 2.2g
>   (4% ADH), Salt 1.6g (27% ADH)

Comment: I tried to keep your expression logic and came to  [`[<>]?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*k(?:cal|j)`](https://regex101.com/r/gW1kO4/1)

Comment: Thank you so much ;) With your's help i rewrote some piece of regex code and it's working  ;)

Comment: Great, I posted it as an answer with explanations. Please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
\d+(?:kcal|kJ)
# require at least one number
# followed by either kcal or kJ
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kB9eF0/1) (or yours: https://regex101.com/r/uS3mE4/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern looks overcomplicated. Probably it is because it serves more complex job than described.

But your taks (get numeric values of kJ and kcal) can be done using pattern like:

```
(\d+[.,]?\d+)(?:kJ|kcal)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my proposition:

```
(\d+)kJ.*?(\d+)kcal
```

1. it extracts the kJ and the kcal number in two differents capturing
   groups
2. it simply captures all numeric chars before "kJ" or "kcal"
   substring
3. it uses lazy quantifier `*?` to avoid consuming the first
   chars of the kcal number.

https://regex101.com/r/uS3mE4/4

Answer (score 0):

You may use alternation and optional (0 or more) spaces between the number and measurement unit:

```
[<>]?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*k(?:cal|j)
```

To be used with the `i` case insensitive modifier.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW1kO4/1).

**Details**:

- `[<>]?` - an optional `<` or `>`
- `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits, and then an optional sequence: a `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `k` - literal `k`
- `(?:cal|j)` - either a `cal` or `j`.